# how to post to a server which has no authentication using curl in Visual Studio 17 c++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am trying to post to server `http://192.168.1.22:8080/user/` which accepts the format `{"age":29,"id":"maverick","name":"Pranjal"}` but insted of inserting a data it returns me xml and css contents of the page. My code is

```
void UserManagement::insertUserData()
{
    /*
    string id=userDetails.getId();
    string name = userDetails.getName();
    string age = userDetails.getAge();
    */
    string insertDetails = "{\"age\":99,\"id\":\"123\",\"name\":\"John\"}";

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
           just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
           data. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        /* Now specify the POST data */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, insertDetails.c_str());

        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();

}
```

I am new to curl so please try to explain in plain English. Thanks in advance.

In the code `url="http://192.168.1.22:8080/user/"`

Comment: your curl request returns exactly what the server response is. So if the data is not inserted because, for example, of an error, handled or not, the response will be what the action called (POST /user) has responded. If you call the wrong url, The response will be what the server responds in case of a 404. Same if it is a 500 error or a 418 :). And generally, you want a html to be rendered, in response to the action call..

Comment: Above code causes undefined behaviour. The reason is that you're using a singular value (`res`) without initializing it. Now, what you need to do is to create a [mcve]. Without that, your question is currently off-topic. Also, the remote side could be at fault, so make sure you can query it using e.g. the cURL commandline tool, `wget` or a similar utility. Provide the working commandline invocation in your question as well. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].